# What can be an example for the 3rd sign of munafiqoon given in Sahih al-Bukhari 33?

Tags: hadith

[Sahih al-Bukhari 33:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/26)

> **Narrated Abu Huraira:**
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The signs of a hypocrite are three:
>
> 1. Whenever he speaks, he tells a lie.
> 2. Whenever he promises, he always breaks it (his promise).
> 3. If you trust him, he proves to be dishonest. (If you keep something as a trust with him, he will not return it.)"

1st and 2nd signs are clear. However 3rd sign is confusing. The description "If you trust him, he proves to be dishonest" is plain and clear, however the comment given in the brackets looks somewhat different or referring to a specific case.

**What kind of case from our life could be the best example to explain this 3rd sign?**

<sup>(I request for 3 examples if possible)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust or "Amanah" refers to when you are given an object or are given responsibilities to take care of.

Taking care of an object would be to keep it safe and return it to the owner as it is when he wants it back. Taking care of responsibilities would be to fulfill them according to how they should be fulfilled.

The Prophet (SAW) even before prophethood was known as "Ameen" meaning "trusted one." This is because he was so trustworthy that people would give him their items to keep safe. The disbelievers would trust him with their objects even after he started preaching Islam.

**Examples:**

1. A person lends you a book. Fulfillment of the trust would be to return the book as it is without damage.
2. You are employed for a job. Fulfillment of the trust would be to not waste work time or cheat your employer in any way.
3. A person is going away for some time and asks you to look after their house. Fulfillment of the trust would be to look after their house correctly.

Allah says in the Quran:

> Indeed, Allah commands you to render trusts to whom they are due and when you judge between people to judge with justice. Excellent is that which Allah instructs you. Indeed, Allah is ever Hearing and Seeing. (4:58)
>
> O you who have believed, do not betray Allah and the Messenger or betray your trusts while you know [the consequence]. (8:27)

Comment: I don't speak Arabic. Is the word "Amanah" in the original arabic text of the Hadith?

Comment: No. Amanah is a noun. The hadith uses a verb. But, they share the same root.